# Why am I getting this error Cannot POST /api/register%0A

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I am trying to create a rest API which will be used in a web app and I am using joi for the validation of the registration of the user. But as I am sending a POST request from postman I am getting this error:

> Cannot POST /api/register%0A

Here is the register.js with the logic:

```
import Joi from 'joi';

const registerControl = {
    register(req,res,next){
    const registerSchema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(100).required(),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')).required(),
        repeat_password: Joi.ref('password'),
    });

    const {error} = registerSchema.validate(req.body)
    console.log(req.body);

    if (error) {
        return next(error);
    }


        res.json({message:"register"});
    }
}


export default registerControl;
```

This is the app.js(where the server will be hosted from):

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import routes from "./routes/index.js";
import { APP_PORT } from "./config/index.js";
import errorHandler from "./middleware/errorHandler.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api', routes);





app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(APP_PORT, ()=>console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.APP_PORT}`));
```

This is the error handler file which is in the middleware folder:

```
import { DEBUG_MODE } from "../config/index.js";
import pkg from "joi";




const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    let statusCode = 500;

    let data = {
        message: "Internal Server Error",
        ...DEBUG_MODE(DEBUG_MODE === 'true' && {originalError: err.message})
    }
    
    const {ValidationError} = pkg;
     if(err instanceof ValidationError){
        statusCode = 422;
        data = {
            message : err.message
        }
    }

    return res.status(statusCode).json(data)

};


export default errorHandler;
```

Here is the index.js file from the routes directory:

```
import express from "express";
import registerControl from "../controllers/auth/register.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', registerControl.register);
export default router;
```

Since I am following a tutorial from youtube, I tried to copy the code from the video and it is still giving me the same error. In response I should be getting back the username,email,password and repeat password that I sent as a POST request back in my console as an object.

Comment: please provide whats in `./routes/index.js`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added the index.js from the routes directory

Comment: cool, you don't have a `/api/register%0A` route, fix what's adding the percent encoded new line

Comment: instead of `/api/register` just try `/register`